# PHP setcookie() error says there are 0 parameters but there are 7 parameters

Tags: php, setcookie

I'm getting the error:

PHP Warning:  setcookie() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in /blah/blah/ on Line x.

This is my entire code.

```
ob_start();
if(isset($_POST['cookies']) && $_POST['cookies'] == "I Accept") {
    setcookie("a-cookie", "Accepted", time()+(86400*90), "/", "mysite.com", 1, true);
} else {
    echo "Invalid Request";
}
ob_end_flush();
```

The code executes perfectly if I remove the setcookie() function, so I know that the rest of my code executes well. But the parameters are not being set.

Comment: Interesting, I've never tried setting a cookie inside an `ob_start` block.

Comment: I wonder if this doesn't work because using `setcookie()` attempts to send it with HTTP headers and adding an output buffer before it sends the header prevents it from adding it to the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't working because I was trying to set it on a different subdomain using a jQuery post function. I have set it to work across subdomains, it just won't set it.

My solution was to move the file where I use setcookie() to the same subdomain and it now works fine.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

It should work.
Try only this:
`setcookie("a-cookie", "Accepted", time()+(86400*90));`